# Query on doubly circular linked list using Java

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Below is the code taken from [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw4/list/DList.java), where methods

`next()` `prev()` `insertAfter()` `insertBefore()` and `remove()`

methods need to get fill with solution.

Before i think of filling the solution, I would like to ask, Whether `DList` abstract data type gets corrupted if a user of `DList` class passes `DListNode` type object to those 5 above mentioned methods. Because How do `DList` class make sure, if this `DListNode` type node is really part of the list?

```
/* DList.java */

package list;

/**
 *  A DList is a mutable doubly-linked list ADT.  Its implementation is
 *  circularly-linked and employs a sentinel (dummy) node at the head
 *  of the list.
 *
 *  DO NOT CHANGE ANY METHOD PROTOTYPES IN THIS FILE.
 */

public class DList {

  /**
   *  head references the sentinel node.
   *  size is the number of items in the list.  (The sentinel node does not
   *       store an item.)
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  protected DListNode head;
  protected int size;

  /* DList invariants:
   *  1)  head != null.
   *  2)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.next != null.
   *  3)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.prev != null.
   *  4)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.next == y, then y.prev == x.
   *  5)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.prev == y, then y.next == x.
   *  6)  size is the number of DListNodes, NOT COUNTING the sentinel,
   *      that can be accessed from the sentinel (head) by a sequence of
   *      "next" references.
   */

  /**
   *  newNode() calls the DListNode constructor.  Use this class to allocate
   *  new DListNodes rather than calling the DListNode constructor directly.
   *  That way, only this method needs to be overridden if a subclass of DList
   *  wants to use a different kind of node.
   *  @param item the item to store in the node.
   *  @param prev the node previous to this node.
   *  @param next the node following this node.
   */
  protected DListNode newNode(Object item, DListNode prev, DListNode next) {
    return new DListNode(item, prev, next);
  }

  /**
   *  DList() constructor for an empty DList.
   */
  public DList() {
    this.head = new DListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
    this.head.next = this.head;
    this.head.prev = this.head;
    this.size = 0;
  }


  /**
   *  next() returns the node following "node" in this DList.  If "node" is
   *  null, or "node" is the last node in this DList, return null.
   *
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @param node the node whose successor is sought.
   *  @return the node following "node".
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public DListNode next(DListNode node) {
    if(node.next != this.head){
        return node.next; 
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  prev() returns the node prior to "node" in this DList.  If "node" is
   *  null, or "node" is the first node in this DList, return null.
   *
   *  Do NOT return the sentinel under any circumstances!
   *
   *  @param node the node whose predecessor is sought.
   *  @return the node prior to "node".
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public DListNode prev(DListNode node) {
    if(node.prev != this.head){
        return node.prev;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  insertAfter() inserts an item in this DList immediately following "node".
   *  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  @param item the item to be inserted.
   *  @param node the node to insert the item after.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertAfter(Object item, DListNode node) {
    //Your solution here
      /*if(node != null){
        node.next = new DListNode(item, node, node.next);
        node.next.next.prev = node.next;
    }*/
  }

  /**
   *  insertBefore() inserts an item in this DList immediately before "node".
   *  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  @param item the item to be inserted.
   *  @param node the node to insert the item before.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void insertBefore(Object item, DListNode node) {
    // Your solution here.
  }

  /**
   *  remove() removes "node" from this DList.  If "node" is null, do nothing.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(1) time.
   */
  public void remove(DListNode node) {
    // Your solution here.
  }

  /**
   *  toString() returns a String representation of this DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THIS METHOD.
   *
   *  @return a String representation of this DList.
   *  Performance:  runs in O(n) time, where n is the length of the list.
   */
  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode current = head.next;
    while (current != head) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }
}
```

---

```
/* DListNode.java */

package list;

/**
 *  A DListNode is a node in a DList (doubly-linked list).
 */

public class DListNode {

  /**
   *  item references the item stored in the current node.
   *  prev references the previous node in the DList.
   *  next references the next node in the DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

   public Object item;
   protected DListNode prev;
   protected DListNode next;


  /**
   *  DListNode() constructor.
   *  @param i the item to store in the node.
   *  @param p the node previous to this node.
   *  @param n the node following this node.
   */
  DListNode(Object i, DListNode p, DListNode n) {
    this.item = i;
    this.prev = p;
    this.next = n;
  }
}
```

My question:

How does `DList` class make sure, whether `DListNode` type node that is passed to those above mentioned methods are genuine? By passing node, Do we have the chance to break the mentioned invariants of `DList` ADT?

Comment: user of `DList` class could have just passed item rather than passing node, but user need access to node to avoid N^2 algo at his side. so user can manipulate `item` but not `prev` and `next` references

Comment: it also does not make sense to compare passed node in  entire list for check of genuine node, when user uses one of these 5 methods. Because this is a costly operation

Comment: The code is precisely as "safe" or "unsafe" as you make it.  It can be written to be totally paranoid, totally unchecked, or can contain some basic checks to catch most usage errors.  That's up to you.

Comment: I did not get your answer. Are you saying that, if check is not done, then corruption of list is possible. If check is done, then those 5 operations is a costly affair?

Comment: How costly is up to you, and your cleverness.

Comment: May be user is suppose to use `Btree` or something other than `DList` to avoid complexity N^2, But my query is for learning purpose. am yet to learn those.

Comment: @HotLicks upto me? it cannot take less than linear time N to search a node in the list.

Comment: Well, note that those methods could be implemented as static methods, with no DList reference provided, since all the necessary info is in the DListNode or it's adjacent partners.  So even if the wrong node is passed in you'd simply operate on a different DList -- you wouldn't necessarily "corrupt" anything.  (Though you should check, eg, that both links are null before inserting a node.)